# Can I install apps on iPhone/iPad from iTunes without syncing?

Tags: iphone, ipad, itunes, data-synchronization, mobile-device-management

Simple question: Can I install an application that was downloaded to my iTunes into my iPad/iPhone without syncing it with the computer?

I am abroad and without access to wi-fi, only network cable, so the trivial solutions of "download directly through the iPad" and "sync it with your computer once and be over it" won't work (unless I start syncing with two computers at the same time, and I recall it gave me trouble in the past).

Comment: possible duplicate: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6846/install-iphone-app-without-itunes-interaction/7572#7572

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the install with iPhone Configuration Utility:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/FA_iPhone_Configuration_Utility/Introduction/Introduction.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution.pdf

Comment: The utility can be downloaded from: http://www.apple.com/support/iphone/enterprise/

Answer (score 0):

No.

To install apps into your iPad you would need to:

1. Install it via the App Store (on your iDevice)
2. Sync it through iTunes

That is, if you don't jailbreak. However, I will not touch on the subject as it may break Apple's license for apps (and void your warranty).

Comment: enterprise apps can be installed directly from a the manufactors homepage, without going through appstore nor itunes.

Comment: whoops, will add that in

Comment: check the duplicate candidate. there are a number of ways to install apps and including @neoneye's suggestion you're still missing at least 2.

Comment: Hmm, seems like a near-exact duplicate. I will add in the other options when I manage to get my MacBook back (can't type that well on the iPhone)

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to download the application (some applications have their own website so you dont have to use iTunes to download them) then drag it into your iPad.

Comment: u actually might even be able to do this with itunes. It would technically "sync" but it would add or subtract any music, etc.

Comment: This is not correct and is not likely to become so. You cannot simply "drag" apps onto an iOS device - you have to use iTunes or the iOS App Store.